# How do I resolve this symbol in windbg?

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to determine the cause of a high cpu condition in windbg, and encounter lines like:

```
196fe804 69088346 00000000 00000000 00000000 System_ni+0x1bbf4b
```

When running '~* kb'

I've set it up so that it loads the symbols from MS' server, but for certain dll's it doesnt seem to work. Specifically:

System.ni
mscorlib.ni
System.Web.ni
System.Web.Mvc.ni
System.Web.Extensions.ni

(I'm not sure where the "ni" comes from)

Anyone with some good ideas?

Comment: you should better try walking the managed stack to make sense of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [NGen'ed images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

In your Windbg type this: `.loadby sos clr`, followed by `!ClrStack`. That will show function names out of managed metadata.